# Node.js request with oAuth2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, request, server-to-server

I have no idea where to start (even where to start searching). I have to make request from Node.js server to another server with oAuth2 authentication. Could anyone give me some clue?

Comment: you can try `request` (https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) for server-to-server communications,

Comment: Thanks but I've foind the solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone have problem with server-to-server communication (Meteor.js server to Google server) using OAuth 2.0 checkout library I've created https://github.com/jagi/meteor-google-oauth-jwt. It makes calling Google REST API from Meteor.js server much simpler.